# In linux how do I do multiple operations on a single string through piping?

Tags: linux, bash, script

For example,

If you do `free -m | sed -n 2p`

I want to work with the output from the **last**, **second to last**, and **third columns**. The problem is I want to keep it consistent and use the output from `free` once.

I want to be able to keep the output consistent without running the `free -m | sed -n 2p` and extracting what the three columns that I need three times; I want to be able to do it once. How can I do this?

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding this correct: You want to generate a dataset, and then generate three new independent datasets based on the original dataset, but without regenerating the original dataset each time? I don't think this can be done simply with piping, but it might be possible with subshelling or temporary files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to give `Awk` a whirl for this.

```
[root@james-ws tmp]# free -m | sed -n 2p
Mem:          3948       3724        223          0        364        852
[root@james-ws tmp]# free -m | sed -n 2p | awk '{print $7, $6, $3}'
852 364 3718
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use named pipes and `awk` to split the output into 3 sources. Then you can read (once) from each source.

```
mkfifo pipe1 pipe2 pipe3
free -m | sed -n 2p | awk '{ print $3 >> pipe1; print $6 >> pipe2; print $7 >> pipe3 }'
```

The named pipes `pipe1` et al. act as buffers that you can read from as if they were pipelines.

```
cat pipe1 | this | that | the-other
```

or preferably without `cat`:

```
this < pipe1 | that | the-other
```

Note that once you read data from a pipe, the data is gone, just as if your input came from a regular pipe.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to do this would be to store the statistics line in a bash array, and then access the elements of the array:

```
memStats=( $(free -m | sed -n 2p) )
memStatElements=${#memStats[@]}
echo "last column: ${memStats[memStatElements-1]}"
echo "second-to-last column: ${memStats[memStatElements-2]}"
echo "second column: ${memStats[1]}" # Note that arrays are 0-based, so [1] is the second element
```

Answer (score 0):

I opted to instead just store the `free` result in a variable and echo each result individually.

This is my end result:

```
STRINGMEM=$(free -m | sed -n 2p | awk '{ print $7,$6,$3 }'); CACHED=$( echo $STRINGMEM | awk '{print $3}'); BUFFERED=$(echo $STRINGMEM | awk '{print $2}'); ACTIVE=$(echo $STRINGMEM | awk '{print $1}'); ACTIVE=$( (( ($BUFFERED + $CACHED) - $ACTIVE)) ); DATE=$(date +%s);
```